# angular 2 and socket.io

Tags: angular, sockets

I recently started programming with angular2 (or it is the 4 version now) anyways, I grasp all the fundementals. The problem I ran into recently is implementing sockets with socket.io.

So basically I have a simple *nodejs express* server listening for socket connections, thats easy.

I create a simple application using angulars-cli terminal *ng*. Simply *ng new application-name*. It creates a minimal working angular application. Now the problem is, how do I add *socket.io-client* into application. I have followed many tutorials, but they all differ in one or the other way. Many of the tutorials are using *systemjs* module loader, but when I create boilerplate with the *ng* no such file with a name *systemjs*.

So my question is how do i tell angular to load socket.io into the app. Ofcourse *import * as io from 'socket.io-client'* into the client isn't enough, as I expierenced. I tried creating *@Injectable()*, then adding it into the approot module as provider, but that seems not to work.

can someone elaborate?

Much appreciated

Comment: can't see any code so can't really help

Comment: please remove the 'angularjs' tag and add 'angular'. The latter is used for angular2+

Answer (score 0):

*It would be helpful to have more details here. What did you make `@Injectable()`? One of your own services, or one of theirs? And give us details about the failure you are referring to in the following statement:*

> Of course `import * as io from 'socket.io'` into the client isn't enough, as I experienced.

---

If you want to just include a script on the page with Angular CLI, you can use the `apps` -> `scripts` array in `.angular-cli.json` ([documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli)).

However, you'll most likely have better luck with a module like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-socket-io. The source for that package can be used as an example of how to import socket.io on its own, too. Simply import the package and use it within your application and the Angular/webpack compilation steps will include the library in your final bundle.

If you are continuing to see issues, then you will need to provide more details.